# Form with list below - List shows blank entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I have a controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def departments
    @users_departments = current_user.departments
    @new_department = current_user.department.new
 end
```

My view looks similar like this:

```
 <%= form_for @new_department, :url => {:action => "departments"} do |f| %>
.
<% end %>

<% @users_departments.each do |dept| %>
  <td><%= dept.name %></td>
  <td><%= dept.employees %></td>
<% end %>
```

@users_departments.each... shows me an empty department. Why? And how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - try to use REST
[form_for doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

something like that:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

will generate link to create action in your UserController

And about @users_departments.each - maybe in your DB current_user.departments.count - return 0

I mean maybe there is no such record in your database.

Comment: Hi Demitriy, I do not really understand. When I create records for my departments (with user_id set) though the current_user, the empty entry is still there. If I remove the form from the view and ALSO THE `@new_department = current_user.department.new` from the controller, the empty entry is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that the magic thing is called lazy and eager loading.

What I made was changing this:

```
@users_departments = current_user.departments
```

to

```
@users_departments = current_user.departments.find(:all)
```

Rails seems to be loading the results in the view if it was called. With "find" in place the db get hit and `@users_departments` fetches "really" the entries. Not in view, like before.